# Database design for pricing overview

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to figure the best design for a pricing overview site for golf courses.

The table that'll hold the eventual price looks like this:

clubid,courseid,seasonid,holesid,timeid,personid,rate

With the fields being:

- clubid: ID of the golf club courseid: a club can have more than one
  course
- seasonid: a club/course has more than one season (high,
  shoulder, low,...)
- holesid: holes a player can play (18,9,allday,...)
- timeid: there can be multiple rates depending on time of day (early,
  prime, twilight,...)
- personid: depending on type of person there can
  be discounts (student, senior) or markup

all those will be further defined in corresponding tables listing the various options.

Now as for my questions:

1. Is there a major design fault in this concept, I miss to see?
2. Are there any issues regarding speed of query with this design? The thing I find most troubling about this multi-dimensional design is the question about data input.
3. What on earth is the best way to enter data in this sort of structure?

I have a barely viable option in mind but don't want to influence others in their thoughts on this just yet.

Answer (score 2):

[Check Here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/). This Will Help you. This has a variety of Data Models. Also it contains for Golf Management.

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/golf_club_management/index.htm

Comment: The model you linked is for a club internal database with pros and members and their associated fees, not the meta-type of DB I'm after. Also a system for daily rates isn't in that model.

Comment: @JoeOtto, Cool, It wont have what you exactly need? There are many different types of data model. You can have that as a reference to start designing your own model.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues with your proposed *star schema* design.

**Issue 1: Flexibility**

By setting the price determination criteria up as a fixed set of foreign keys to lookup tables, you create a situation where every course that you want to track prices for must somehow be fit into this scheme.  As soon as you come to a course with a creative marketing manager you could find yourself having to modify your schema just to accomodate that one course.

**Issue 2: Data Input Effort**

As you've already noticed, having a set of fixed price determinants means that the cross-product of all of these determinants is a huge pile of data to have to maintain.  The thing that will be frustrating about this is that, for many courses, some determinants won't matter.

Another potentially frustrating thing could be that each course could have their own interpretation of each determinant.  For example, what does *peak season* mean to each course?  If you don't care about these details then you're OK, but if you actually have to explain yourself in specific terms (i.e. what dates do we mean by "peak" at course *X*?) then you will also have a lot of data in your price dimension tables too.

**Addressing the Issues:**

If you are willing to go with a more complex data model, you can cut down the amount of data management *significantly*.  Instead of a star schema with a fixed set of price point determinants, you can table-drive the determinants.  The schema would be something like this:

```
COURSE              -- The list of courses you are tracking
  courseid (PK)
, name

COURSE_PRICE_POINT  -- An individual price point for a course
  cppid (PK)
, courseid          -- FK to COURSE
, price             -- The amount, if your system is multi-currency, include a code 
                    -- for the currency, e.g. GBP, EUR, USD, etc.

COURSE_PRICE_FACTOR -- The list of factors that make a specific price point applicable
  cppid (PK)        -- PK, also FK to COURSE_PRICE_POINT
, pfid (PK)         -- PK, also part of FK to FACTOR_VALUE
, fvid              --     the other part of the FK to FACTOR_VALUE

FACTOR_VALUE        -- A lookup table of price factors, e.g. "Peak Season", "18 Holes"
  pfid (PK)         -- PK, also FK to PRICE_FACTOR
, fvid (PK)
, value             -- Description of the price factor value

PRICE_FACTOR        -- A list of the dimensions that impact price, 
                    -- e.g. Season, Holes, Person, Time
  pfid (PK)
, description       -- A caption/name for the price factor.
```

The way the model works is that for each specific price that a course might charge, you have a record in `COURSE_PRICE_POINT`.  There would be one record in this table for each record that you might have in your star schema pricing table, *if your star schema table could have the minimum number of rows possible*.

The price determinant columns in your star schema pricing table become rows in `PRICE_FACTOR`.  The values that might appear in your determinant lookup tables become rows in `FACTOR_VALUE`.  This part is the same amount of work except that if you find that you need to add a new price factor, all you need to do is enter some new data instead of changing your table definitions, which is what you'd be up against with the star schema approach.

To actually pin the price point to its determining factors you populate `COURSE_PRICE_FACTOR` to connect the price point to the **minimum set** of factor values that are needed to define the price point.  Note that `FACTOR_VALUE` is identified by its FK to `PRICE_FACTOR`.  This means that the PK of `PRICE_FACTOR` is found on `COURSE_PRICE_FACTOR` as part of the FK to `FACTOR_VALUE`.  This is important because it lets you define a unique index on the combination of price point ID and price factor ID (I've made that combination the PK of the table).  This means that the schema will impose the restriction that you can't have contradictory values for the same price factor, which is a nice little data consistency constraint.

All of this may seem like a lot of work, so why is it better than star schema?  To look at one example, let's say that you have four variations of each of season, holes, time and person in your star schema.  That is probably an under-estimate, but let's go with that.  This means you need 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 = 256 records per course to track all of the pricing variations.  What if a course has a very simple price card, say: "off-season is all you can play for $100 per day".  This would be one price point in my suggested model but star schema would still need 1 x 4 x 4 x 4 = 64 records.

What's worse is this:  With the star schema, depending on how you intend to use it, you may have a rule that says each lookup table value needs to be represented in the pricing table for each course.  That would mean that adding a new record to, say *season* would require a bunch of new records in every course, even if the other courses don't recognize your new dimension value.

The primary advantages of my suggested model are (i) that you can be very specific and accurate about the pricing for a particular course under specific conditions and (ii) that your data maintenance is minimized.

What is the drawback of this model?  This model won't be very helpful for setting up a price comparison chart for one course against another.  If the two courses you're comparing have very different pricing structures, it will be very difficult to find a way to show the price lists in a side-by-side price comparison table.

Comment: Thanks Joel for this detailed answer! Actually what I intended to (in my layman's ways) was something like this: as you rightly indicated it's certain that not every course will have seperate rates for students, seniors, out of state visitors, etc. Therefore I would ask first what person categories they have and save that to another table (courseid, personid) to show that that particular course uses only the listed person categories. The persons table will of course hold all the possible categories (courses may add additional categories if those present don't fit).

Comment: Same for all the other FK fields. That way I thought that the data input would be simplyfied, as each course only gets the input options it needs and not the other unused categories. In that way that obviously would reduce the number of records needed. Is that a crude workaround in the expert's eyes? I'll take a closer look at your proposed model to figure it out in the meantime ;)

Comment: @JoeOtto - If you had your pricing table point to the "used categories" M:N tables instead of the category tables themselves, then you would have what is known as a _snowflake schema_ instead of a _star schema_.  This would work because it ensures (using referential integrity) that each course can only use the appropriate values.  While this is a reasonable solution it still requires a schema change if a new category of price determinant is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Concept seems fine, Speed of your query will depend on the number of variables for each, but it should be pretty easy to optimize with good indexes, `courseid` and `seasonid` seem like quick candidates. This also lends nicely to a tree structure that you could load into memory which would have amazingly fast look up times.

What you are doing is pretty common - It's called a [Star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema), and I know that many financial institutions handle their pricing in this manner.